# Is $\int_C P dx + Q dy = \int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

I am a bit confused about some notation. For a vector field $\vec{F}$, I understand the notation
$$
\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}.
$$
But I have also seen the notation
$$
\int_C P dx + Q dy
$$
If $\vec{F} = \langle P, Q\rangle$, are these two the same? (I am guessing that this is so from examples I have seen in calculating them.)

Comment: Though they are the same, until and unless you get to differential forms you should just use the first notation.  If someone gives you a exercise with the second, your first step should just be to convert to the first.  Once there you parametrize $C$ by some path $\vec r(t)$ over $a\le t \le b$ and then use $$\int_C \vec F\cdot d\vec r = \int_a^b \left[\vec F\left(\vec r(t)\right)\cdot \vec r'(t)\right]dt$$ which is just a regular Riemann integral.  This will hopefully cause the least confusion.

Comment: @Bye_World: Thank you for the comment. Would you elaborate on the reasons for avoiding the notation? I have posted a new question on this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503705/motivation-behind-notation-int-c-p-dx-q-dy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. If $\vec{F} = (P,Q)$ and $d\vec{r} = (dx,dy)$, then $$\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = (P,Q) \cdot (dx,dy) = Pdx + Qdy$$