# Calculating $d(xdx + z^2dy + xydz)$

Tags: calculus, differential-forms

Inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1505057/171192), I am trying to learn about differential forms. I am going through [these notes](http://math.umn.edu/~bpawlows/teaching/324sp12/ec3.pdf) were (on page 3) $d(xdx + z^2dy + xydz)$. I believe that the formula that I should use is
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz.
$$
So for example I get
$$
d(xy) = ydx + xdy.
$$
The notes seem to say that $d(xy) = dx + dy$ so I am a bit confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure here you get that from the notes.  And the formula you are using is only for a 0-form, while this problem is for a 1-form.

Comment: @Paul: I get this from page 3 in the notes.

Comment: James is right: it is indeed a typo.  An easy way for you to check is to use the statement the notes make on the bottom of that page: "If $\alpha$ is a 1-form, then $d\alpha$ is the curl of $\alpha$".  If you compute the curl of $(x,z^2,xy)$ you can confirm that the author made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo. It is indeed true that $d(xy)=ydx+xdy$. In short, to calculate with differential forms you take total derivatives paired with the wedge product. The wedge product has $dx_i \wedge dx_j= -dx_j\wedge dx_i $ hence $dx_i \wedge dx_i=0$ for all $i$. Then, you extend that rule naturally. In the same way, we could say complex numbers are just real numbers paired with some new element $i$ such that $i^2=-1$ then multiplication and addition proceeds as usual.

Comment: @John Doe you can look at http://www.supermath.info/math332mission8f2013soln.pdf see Problem 78 for another example. I try to weave a fair amount of these basic differential form calculations into my Advanced Calculus course.

Comment: Thanks James. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Let $f$ and $g$ be functions, $\phi$ and $\psi$ $1$-forms. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
(1)&\;\mathrm{d}(fg)=\mathrm{d}f\;g+f\;\mathrm{d}g\\
(2)&\;\mathrm{d}(f\phi)=\mathrm{d}f\wedge\phi\\
(3)&\;\mathrm{d}(\phi\wedge\psi)=\mathrm{d}\phi\wedge\psi-\phi\wedge\mathrm{d\psi}.
\end{align*}
$$

Notice that $\wedge$ denotes the [wedge product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WedgeProduct.html).